# Karate - XML - Printing Child node

Tags: xml, karate

I need to print a certain child node of my XML which is having multiple child nodes. I have given a sample xml below. But, karate converts to json and prints the data in json format; but i need it to be returned in XML.

**XML:**

```
    * def xml = 
"""
<ns4:root xmlns:ns4="http://foo.com" xmlns:ns5="http://bar.com">
 <ns4:Test>
  <ns5:code>123</ns5:code>
  <ns5:description>My Description</ns5:description>
  <ns5:SubTest>
     <ns6:code>345</ns6:code>
     <ns6:description>Your Description</ns6:description>
     <ns6:categoryCode>BH</ns6:categoryCode>
  </ns5:SubTest>
  <ns5:SubTest>
     <ns6:code>567</ns6:code>
     <ns6:description>Your Description</ns6:description>
     <ns6:categoryCode>BH</ns6:categoryCode>
  </ns5:SubTest>
  <ns5:SubTest>
     <ns6:code>784</ns6:code>
     <ns6:description>Your Description</ns6:description>
     <ns6:categoryCode>BH</ns6:categoryCode>
  </ns5:SubTest>
  <ns5:categoryCode>DUDU</ns5:categoryCode>
  <ns5:unwanted>Unwanted XML Parameter</ns5:unwanted>
 </ns4:Test>
 <ns4:Test>
  <ns5:code>675</ns5:code>
  <ns5:description>His Description</ns5:description>
  <ns5:unwanted>Unwanted XML Parameter</ns5:unwanted>
 </ns4:Test>
</ns4:root>
"""
```

This is the xpath query i am using to print second SubTest node with code = 567.

```
* def PP_XML = $xml/root/Test/SubTest[2]/*
* print PP_XML
```

This gives response like this;

```
13:40:19.391 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] [
    "567",
    "Your Description",
    "BH"
  ]
```

Is there any way i can isolate and print only second child SubTest node in proper XML?

I tried with below one too; but without luck.

```
* def PP_XML = $xml/root/Test/SubTest[2]
* print PP_XML
```

I tried elimination process as well, by excluding other 2 child nodes like below; this throws 'cannot convert to xml' error. I know this is how karate handles xml but wanna know if i can reproduce this.

```
* def PP_XML = $xml/root/Test/*[not(self::SubTest[1]) or (self::SubTest[3])]
* xml PP = PP_XML
* print PP
```

Comment: * def PP_XML = $xml/root/Test/SubTest[2]                 This should work

Comment: hey sandeep - please have the courtesy to provide well-formed XML - you have at least 5 typos because of cut-and-paste

Comment: @sandeep modified your XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
* def PP_XML = $xml/root/Test/SubTest[2]
* print PP_XML
```

Gives:

```
15:21:24.723 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] <ns5:SubTest>
  <ns6:code>567</ns6:code>
  <ns6:description>Your Description</ns6:description>
  <ns6:categoryCode>BH</ns6:categoryCode>
</ns5:SubTest>
```

Seems to work just fine.