# Karate: Unable to replace embedded expression value inside a XML chunk read from a JS function

Tags: karate

Unable to replace embedded expression value inside a XML chunk read from a JS function, had a look at string to XML conversion. But unable to figure out what am I missing,

Scenario file has below, which calls a js function to get XML chunk containing a embedded expression,

```
* def customerNumber = functions.getRandomNumber()
* xml Security1 = functions.fetchSecExistMort()
* print Security1
```

Sharing JS function in my next comment.

Below is my javascript function,

```
function()
{
return {
fetchPrimaryResiAddress: function()
{
var PrimaryResidentialAddress =
`<Address>
<StreetNo>#(customerNumber)</StreetNo>
<Street Type="Street">RAWSON</Street>
<City>DEAKIN</City>
<State Name="ACT"/>
<Postcode>2600</Postcode>
<Country ISO3166="AU"/>
</Address>`;
return PrimaryResidentialAddress;
}
getRandomNumber: function()
{
var temp = '';
karate.repeat(14, function(){ temp += Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1 });
return temp;
}
}
}
```

As part of print outcome, embedded expression #(customerNumber) isnt getting updated to customerNumber value

Comment: sorry this is too complex for me to understand and I'll see if I can come back later. my suggestion is please don't use JS like this for XML - I'm sure you can figure out how to do embedded expressions without it. if you run out of ideas, just do brute-force string-replace: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682733/143475 I personally would never have a function within a function, I think you haven't read the docs properly. if you read a JS function, you can invoke it within a feature file. don't `call` a JS file un-necessarily. there is more, but I'll stop here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded expressions will not work within JS. It is designed to work only within feature files, or when using the `read()` API.

If you are using JS, just do some string-concatenation and move-on.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Checked replacing js with a feature file and it worked.